# How can I put humanity on Santa's naughty list?

Tags: achievements, plague-inc

There is an achievement called "On the Naughty List", related to the scenario "Santa's Little Helper" (featuring the Neurax Worm that wants to restore happiness) and that asks me to put the humanity on Santa's naughty list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to do this under Scenario mode: Santa's Little Helper

Buy the first two: Santa's little neurax worm, and festive tendrils.  Then buy: sloth, gluttony, jealousy, and intoxication.

It should unlock shortly after this.

Comment: Please note that for the Intoxication syptom you need to buy Indulgence and Partying first.